# Long PL/SQL output in SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Got problem with executing my script under SQLPLUS. Under SQL Developer it works well.

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000
declare
yyy varchar2(32000):='';
begin
yyy := 'XxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzz';
yyy := yyy || 'XxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzz';
yyy := yyy || 'XxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzzXxxYyyZzz';
dbms_output.put_line(yyy);
end;
/
```

Under SQLPLUS I get error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Any solution how to force running scripts with long output under SQLPLUS? I need output on because I spool results to file.

Comment: Works fine for me in SQL*Plus.

Comment: I have SQL*Plus version which was added to Oracle 10g installation.. and it gives such a error on multiple computers (win7 or xp no matter). I run SQL*Plus and then I call script with content as above by: `@script.sql`. Maybe my version is bugged?

Comment: It works fine in my Sql*plus too.

Comment: I had the same error in oracle 8i when i try to print more than 255 characters in sqlplus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a Oracle client older than Oracle 10g  against an Oracle 10g Database

Please find the quote from ASKTOM below

The problem is NOT during runtime, you are apparently using an old client against a 10.2 or above database. The database code *runs fine*

It is when the client goes to PICK UP THE STRING from the database that you are hitting the exception.

sqlplus is doing something like this:

a) call procedure/code - it runs and fills a dbms_output buffer, an array in a package.

b) then sqlplus calls dbms_output.GET_LINES to get the buffered output to print. THIS is the call that fails.

For more information Kindly refer

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1011431134399